# Drop Down List DataBindings SelectedValue

Tags: c#, windows, data-binding

Here is My Dropdown DataSource:

```
dropReagent.DataSource =
    from customerz in db.tblCustomers
    select new
    {
        Agent = customerz.Name + " " + customerz.Family + " - " + customerz.CustomerID,
        AgentID = customerz.CustomerID
    };
dropReagent.DisplayMember = "Agent";
dropReagent.ValueMember = "AgentID";
```

I have add a DataBindings to SelectedValue:

```
dropReagent.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", db.tblCustomers.First(x => x.CustomerID == ID), "ReagentID");
```

Now Here is SelectedValueChanged event:

```
private void dropReagent_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dropReagent.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
        db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But when I change selected Value I will get this error:

> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Where is wrong? And what should I do to have a clean data bindings to drop down selected value?

Comment: Is the exception thrown on the line where you call `WriteValue` ?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, it's right.

Comment: Then you have not added any databindings. Maybe you swallow an exception when `Add()` is called or maybe you are calling things out of order. Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: What about Types? The selected Value is a string but the target Data bound is an integer in database.

Comment: I don't think you would get that error for a type mismatch problem. You may get it after you fix your first problem.

Comment: Unless of course that is the cause of an exception that is not handled.